# Why does the following error occur when building?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.x

Does anyone know what causes the following error?
I use FB SDK and Firebase SDK in my game, then this error just appear when I building.

```
[com.facebook.android:facebook-common:16.2.0] C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\11a3e6e9b13160b69e16c469635e49f1\AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-55 Error:
    Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.facebook.android:facebook-common:16.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-55
[com.facebook.android:facebook-common:16.2.0] C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\11a3e6e9b13160b69e16c469635e49f1\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
Note: D:\work\CatVillage_LogIn\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

0x00007ff70294b5cd (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff702952329 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff7038b9713 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff703f4314d (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff701aa6bd2 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x000001a7e8e21193 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x000001a7e8e20e7b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x000001a7e8e20c00 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x000001a5a48da6a5 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x000001a5adcde233 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x000001a5a43c843b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x000001a5adcd77d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
0x000001a5a65444f3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x000001a5a6543c08 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x000001a5a6543f35 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ff99deae0a4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff99ddee744 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff99ddee8dc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff70286fd84 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff70286a9a4 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff7042b23c1 (Unity) CallMono
0x00007ff7042ba527 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff7042b51af (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x00007ff7042b324e (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x00007ff7042a73cd (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff70215953d (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff70207490f (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x000001a5a434d7e7 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x000001a5a434d003 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x000001a5a43498d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x000001a8fe52c103 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x000001a8fe517f83 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x000001a8fc013553 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x000001a6127e8aaa (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x000001a6127e88c3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x000001a6127d818b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x000001a61273e27f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x000001a61273d37b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x000001a5abc5014b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x000001a5aab1ff03 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x000001a5aab3fd8b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000001a5aab3fc73 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x000001a8d6b4742b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000001a8d6b36478 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x000001a5aab3d0e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001a8d6b3468e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x000001a8d6b3418b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001a8d6b3accb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x000001a8d6b39043 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x000001a8d6b38f7b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x000001a8d6b34413 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x000001a8d6b33ac3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000001a8d6b3393b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x000001a8d6ccdbcb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x000001a8d6ccd673 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x000001a8d6ccd42f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x000001a8d6ccd34b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x000001a8d6ccd19d (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x000001a8d6ccd256 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ff99deae0a4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff99ddee744 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff99ddee8dc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff70286fd84 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff70286a9a4 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff7028642c5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff70296ceba (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff7033a5856 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff7038e9bdb (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff7033a566a (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff7038eaaf7 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff7038e46fc (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffa452b8241 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ffa452b7d01 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff7038bf733 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff7038c417b (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff704be582e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffa464a257d (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffa474caa68 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

I have changed the Androidmanifest.xml of the target file and even deleted the external folder, but line 18 of the Androidmanifest.xml of the target folder will change back to
 when building.